# Exception design in web service

Tags: java, rest, exception

In a web RESTful service, I need to call 3rd service, how can I graceful return the error message?

In my opinion, it's like this:

1. DB operate error
   DBService layer, print the error stack in log, and throws Exception with a message simply describe the error reason, such as "record is not exist" or "primary key conflict" and so on.The rest service layer catch the Exception, and return 500 with this error message.
2. 3rd system error
   The service which call the 3rd system, log the error, and don't return the error stack in rest response, it only throws Exception with a message, such as "template is not exist" and so on.The rest service layer catch the Exception, and return 500 with this error message.

Actually, the flow for the two case is almost the same, I think it's very simple, but I don't know it is a good design.

I want to tell us more reasons about the error, but can't directly return the error call stack to user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a good approach. You can throw your custom exceptions and yes, in the controller catch the exception and return the corresponding error code with message